# Shiny titlepanel: how to put title and image at same height?

Tags: r, image, position, shiny, title

I want both a title and an image in my titlepanel, but the title on the left and the image on the right.
I got them both in the panel using this code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel(div("Fenologische modellen", 
                   img(height = 105, width = 300, src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg"))
   ),
```

[image]

But then they're just next to eachother.
Because align did not work for the image (or "style = ...", tried that too), I decided to put them both in different columns, which requires a fluidRow first.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel( 
    fluidRow( 
      column(4, "Fenologische modellen"),
      column(4, offset = 8, img(height = 105, width = 300, src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg"))
    )
  ),
```

What happens is that the image is indeed placed on the right, but it's been placed bottom right, while I need it to be on the same line as the title.

[image]

I've tried adjusting the height of the columns in pixels, but under a certain height, it didn't change anymore. The picture above shows the limit.

Any suggestions?

PS: I do not want to group both of them in a wellpanel, unless I can make it completely white and thus invisible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured it out myself while trying to solve the same problem in a wellPanel.
The bad guy is the `offset`  argument in `column()`. If I remove it, the image and title are horizontally aligned.

To put the image on the right, I just have to make the left column very wide:

```
titlePanel(
  fluidRow(
    column(9, "Fenologische modellen"), 
    column(3, img(height = 105, width = 300, src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg"))
  )
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
titlePanel(div("Fenologische modellen", 
                img(height = 105, width = 300, 
                    src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg", 
                    class = "pull-right")))
```

The `pull-right` class is a Bootstrap class that seems to do what you want.

Comment: It does move the image exactly to where I want it, 
but now it doesn't consider the titlepanel anymore. It overlaps both the titlepanel and the next wellpanel...

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `column` the `offset` argument is

"The number of columns to offset this column **from the end of the previous column**."

Your first column takes up 4 units out of 12. Then a column is added 8 units apart from the end of the last column, meaning that you are starting your new column after 4+8 = 12 units out of 12. Since 4 units + 4 offset + 4 units = 12 units, the correct use of the `offset` argument would be

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel( 
    fluidRow( 
      column(4, "Fenologische modellen"),
      column(4, offset = 4, img(height = 105, width = 300, src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg"))
    )
  )
```